# would like iphone view with feed of all twitter tweets with a given hashtag

Tags: iphone, twitter, feed, hashtag

What is the simplest way to display this kind of feed? I've heard you can do this with
Yahoo pipes, but does Twitter directly support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23weloveyouss501

there is your hash tag... see at the right there is an rss feed of this query:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23weloveyouss501

brilliant - now all you need is TouchXML and this function:

```
-(void)getRSSFeed:(NSString *)XMLString {

    blogEntries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; // blogEntries in header

    NSError *theError;
    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:XMLString options:0 error:&theError] autorelease];

    if(theError){
        NSLog(@"An error");
    }

    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];

    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }
        [blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]]; // blog entries set in header
    }

}
```

if you output `blogEntries` you will see all the entries. :) Now you can get at them easily. :)

Comment: You know that `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` is the same as `[NSMutableArray array]` right?

Comment: Also, you leak memory when adding the retained copy `blogItem`. Doing `blogItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` and then later `[blogEntries addObject: blogItem]` will solve that.

Comment: ah, fair enough mate - I didn't write it... can't remember where I got it from now, although its somewhat modified, so might be my fault. :/ Ah, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas Clayson.  So, to get a real-time feed, I would: 1) do an HTTP get on the atom url 2) pass the result into getRSSFeed  3) display results 4) run timer and repeat for real-time ?

Comment: I would make a custom class that does an asynchronous url request (NSURLConnection) and fetches those results. Then I would run a timer, as you say, to run that class over and over again. Then in my custom class I would have a delegate method that gets called once the script has completed and have the method `reloadData` the main table view (if thats how you're doing it). :) hope this helps